# Getting null Response in an jQuery AJAX call to a WebMethod but Web Method returns JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables, webmethod

I am getting null/ undefined response for a jQuery AJAX call. I am trying to bind data to a Jquery Data table in asp.net webforms. When I try to parse the data it gives me an Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 Error. I am suspecting issue could be with JSON data but I have validated json output at JSONlint.com.
It must me some stupid error but I am unable to figure it out and I have wasted hours troubleshooting it.

jQuery Ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ShowData').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'Default.aspx/fetchDetails',
                dataType: 'json',                    
                data: "{'JobID':'" + $('#txtJobID').val() + "'}",
                success: function (response) {
                    //var d = JSON.parse(data);
                    var data = response.d;
                    alert(typeof (data)); //gives out object
                    alert(response.d); //gives out null
                    $('#tblBasicInfo').dataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'JobId' },
                            { 'data': 'UserId' },
                            { 'data': 'UserName' },
                            { 'data': 'Cas' },
                            { 'data': 'Question' },                                
                            { 'data': 'Language' },
                            { 'data': 'Appl' },
                        ]
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(xhr.responseJSON);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

WebMethod

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static void fetchDetails(string JobID)
    {
        var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"];
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.ToString());

        String query = "Select TOP 1 * FROM TAble where Jobid =@JobID";
        DataTable dtBasicInfo = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", Int32.Parse(JobID));
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(a);
        da.Fill(dtBasicInfo);
        SqlDataReader value = a.ExecuteReader();
        con.Close();
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtBasicInfo.Rows)
        {
            childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtBasicInfo.Columns)
            {
                childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);
            }
            parentRow.Add(childRow);
        }
        var jsk = jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);
    }
```

JSON

```
[{"JobId":123456789,"UserId":"asdf3a     ","UserName":"Pekki, Barb                      ","Cas":263,"Question":"Q12345","Language":"ENG","Appl":300}]
```

Comment: I have posted an answer. You are doing web methods in the wrong way. You need to keep some simple points in mind when dealing with web methods, which I have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the following points are implemented in your code and then it will all work like it should. Use uppercase D when you call the datatable API as in `$('#tblBasicInfo').DataTable({`

1. Your issue is that you are returning a `void` from your WebMethod.
   You need to return a C# object from the web method `fetchDetails`.
2. You don't need to create JSON or do any serialization in the
   WebMethod because ASP.Net framework will do that work for you; just
   return a valid object from your C# code and it will all work fine.
3. Also, remove the data type flag you have mentioned just above
   `fetchDetails` method as its not needed.  I have removed all the
   serialization code from your fetchDetails method as its not needed.
   Simply return a C# object of a class from your web method.

So, in your case define an instance of this class in your method `fetchDetails`.

**Job class**

```
public class Job {

  public int JobId {get;set;}
  public string UserId {get;set;}
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public int Cas {get;set;}
  public string Question {get;set;}
  public string Language {get;set;}
  public int  Appl {get;set;}

}
```

**fetchDetails method returning Job type**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static Job fetchDetails(string JobID)
{
    var conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"];
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.ToString());

    String query = "Select TOP 1 * FROM TAble where Jobid =@JobID";
    DataTable dtBasicInfo = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    a.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobID", Int32.Parse(JobID));
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(a);
    da.Fill(dtBasicInfo);
    SqlDataReader value = a.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();

    //WRITE CODE to populate a Job object
     Job job = new Job();
    //set properties of job object before returning it as in code below
   If (dtBasicInfo. Rows. Count > 0)
   { 
    job.JobId =  Int32.Parse(JobID);
    job.UserId = dtBasicInfo.Rows[0]["UserId"].toString();
    job.UserName = dtBasicInfo.Rows[0]["UserName"].toString();
   } 

   return job;
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes but data table still populates 0 records :(

Comment: How ever        alert(response.d);  now gives me object Object instead of type null but data table is not loading any records.

Comment: That is a different problem and not related to webmethod returning a null. You have to make sure your table in database has records.  Slso, you don't need datareader in your code since you are getting a DataTable.

Comment: Response.d will be a Javascript object and that is correct.  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: database has records, I am getting the data from DB and response.d should be javascript object but I dont understande why binding is not happening when everything seems to be in place. Vould you please take a look at my ajax code. I am new to this and suspecting I am missing something

Comment: success: function (response) {
                    //var d = JSON.parse(data);
                    var data = response.d;
                    alert(typeof (data)); //gives out object
                    alert(response.d); //gives out null
                    $('#tblBasicInfo').dataTable({
                        paging: false,
                        data: data,

Comment: Suspecting error in this part of code. DAta Reader is removed. I was trying something and forgot to comment it out.

Comment: Can you put a break point in your webmethod and check if `dtBasicInfo` is being populated in your webmethod?

Comment: YEs I have checked. Data is there in dtBasicinfo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164451/discussion-between-tushit-nagda-and-sunil).